# Can someone please help me out by pointing and correcting the error here as I would like to repeat the message every 24 hours?

Tags: python

Can someone please help me out by pointing and correcting the error here as I would like to repeat the message every 24 hours?

```
import requests
import time
Message=['For new members here,Maintain discipile,No use of harsh language,Only youtube links are to 
be shared,No abusive or intimadating content,Or else will get kicked out.,]
for Message in Message:
print(Message)
base_url='bot'surl/sendMessage?
chat_id:******&text="{}".format(Message)
request.get(base_url)
print(base_url)
time.sleep(3600)
```

Comment: Does the syntax highlighting in your code above give you any hints as to what's wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, question titles should concisely summarize the question so other users can tell what they're about. Yours doesn't do that at all. When you ran this code you got an error, right? That would have been a good place to start. Search for that error message and see what might have caused it. And please always include exact error messages in questions when you ask them.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing closing quotes in your strings.

`base_url` also needs an escape character `\` in bot's, as Python interprets that as a closing quote. the `\` tells it that you would like it to be interpreted as a character.

```
import requests
import time
Message=['For new members here,Maintain discipile,No use of harsh language,Only youtube links are to 
be shared,No abusive or intimadating content,Or else will get kicked out.,']
for Message in Message:
print(Message)
base_url='bot\'surl/sendMessage?chat_id:******&text="{}"'.format(Message)
request.get(base_url)
print(base_url)
time.sleep(3600)
```